# Convert list of strings to an enum list (One,Two,etc)

Tags: unity-game-engine, enums

I've searched a lot but can't find a clear answer anywhere for *string list* -> *enum*.
I've got a list of strings that I want to turn into an *enum* that I can select from in **Unity** inspector.

Specifically, I'm trying to make an *enum* list of all the currently set-up Input buttons from project settings. I've got all the names, just don't know how to make it an *enum* or similar. Ideally showing up like a *KeyCode* variable in inspector.

Currently trying (and failing) with:

```
foreach (string s in names)
{
    if (Enum.TryParse(s, true, out list))
        Debug.Log(list);
    else Debug.Log("FAILED");
}
```

"names" = `static List<string> names;`
"list" = `static MyList list;`
"MyList" = `enum MyList { Null }`

Returns "FAILED" 58 times for only 29 Input axis.

I want a simple solution, so if its not possible or relatively simple, I'll work out something else.

Code for getting the "names" list of strings (Works correctly):

```
var inputManager = AssetDatabase.LoadAllAssetsAtPath("ProjectSettings/InputManager.asset")[0];
SerializedObject obj = new SerializedObject(inputManager);
SerializedProperty axisArray = obj.FindProperty("m_Axes");
if (axisArray.arraySize == 0)
    Debug.Log("No Axes");

for (int i = 0; i < axisArray.arraySize; ++i)
{
    var axis = axisArray.GetArrayElementAtIndex(i);
    var name = axis.FindPropertyRelative("m_Name").stringValue;
    names.Add(name);
}
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.parse?view=netframework-4.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up making my own solution, since (and please correct me if I'm wrong) the TryParse() and Parse() methods appear to need the enum to **already contain** entries with the same name (or index int) as the string to parse. This defeats the purpose for me, since I am doing this because I **don't** have the names in there already.

My solution ended up being to switch to having a single string input variable instead of an enum, then use Odin Inspector's ValidateInput attribute to check (*for spelling errors, and*) if the input variable matches any of the string entries in my dynamic list of InputManager input names (which I update manually using Odin Inspector's Button attribute and the code in the original post).

It's slightly less clean than I wanted, but does the job, so I'm satisfied.

Answer (score 1):

Normally you can do

`foreach (string colorName in Enum.GetNames(typeof(Colors)))`  which will iterate the names of the enums.

In your code above you havent shown what list is, nor where names has come from. However.

`enum Things
{
  Item1 = 0,
  Item2 = 1
}`

You can get the name from `string name = Enum.GetName(typeof(Things), (int)Things.Item2)` and you can get values from names with `int value = (int)Enum.Parse(typeof(Things), nameOfThing)`

So depending on what you actually want in a list and what you start with, iterate through and pick the relevant one

Comment: What you're doing is not directly enum related, if you look in your asset you'll see it a simple bunch of text, and the "down" button is not listed as "keycode.down" but you could take those values and get the keycode value..  However, Im not a code writing service.

Comment: I understand that the names values are not actually functional keycodes or anything. I'm just trying to make an enum of just their names so I can then do a `if (Input.GetButtonDown(specifiedEnumEntry) { Do stuff }`, so I can make a kind of input listener set up through inspector.

Comment: That makes no sense as the input system does it for you, but you can still use the code above

Comment: Theres valid reasons for it, but thanks anyway for the help. I'll try and get it working.

Comment: Well you can convert those values to keycodes as per code in my answer..